# Contain method, check string previous char

Tags: c#

This is my code :

```
string keyword = "bil"

if(description.Contains(keyword))
{
    do something...
}
```

description is just string. 
How to check if keyword's previous char is whitespace then do something else. For example if description is:

```
description = "gobil bla bla"
```

This code is true:

```
if(description.Contains(keyword))
{
    do something...
}
```

But bil previous characther is o "gobil" not whitespace.  One solution is to use foreach char loop , but description is a long string that would ruin my application perfomance.

Comment: Use the [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), Luke!

Comment: split your description by " " and check if index of variable keyword > 0

Comment: What if the match is at the start of the string and there's no "previous char"? Also, do you only want the previous char but don't care about the next char (i.e. does `bla bilgo` contain a valid match)?

Comment: Yes i care only previous char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a regular expression that matches a word-boundary, followed by your *keyword* followed by another word-boundary:

```
if(new Regex(@"\b" + keyword + @"\b").IsMatch(description))
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if(description.StartsWith(keyword) || description.Contains(" "+keyword))
```

Comment: But if description start with keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the string and look for each occurrence of the keyword. For each occurrence, check if occurrence is at beginning of string or previous char is space:

```
bool Contains(string description, string keyword)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        index = description.IndexOf(keyword, index);
        if (index == -1) // Not in string.
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (index == 0) // Start of string.
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(description[index - 1])) // Is previous index whitespace?
        {
            return true;
        }
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually maybe my keyword is "tbc bank"  and in that  case it wont work

Comment: Updated the answer to handle the new requirement.